# problem with call webservice with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i wrote some code below but it doesnt work 
Web Service has web method helloworld, it doesn't take any parameters and returns a string.

javascript

```
function onclickkk() {

    var mes = $('#txt_1').val();
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ message: mes });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mylocalhost/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (respons) {
            alert(respons.d);
        }
    });
}
```

webservice

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void HelloWorld(string message)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing `string message` with a class that has a field message.

Comment: Add and error handler after the success and see what error is returned `,error: function (error) {  alert(error); }`

Comment: I think a `webmethod` accepts by default Http GET requests.Try adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your web service method, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add error recovery to see what type of error it is.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mylocalhost/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld',
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, this should be a comment and not an answer as it doesn't solve the problem, it simply helps uncover what the problem should be. Just a friendly heads up in the even someone downvotes this.

Comment: Hi travis 
You are right, but the original post does not specify exactly what the error is, so I wanted to help in discovering it.
In the comment, the code does not look good.